# How to use installed version of chrome in Playwright?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webautomation, playwright

I want to use chrome instead of chromium. I can achieve the same in puppeteer by providing executable path. In playwright it doesn't work as browser type argument supports only 'chromium, webkit, firefox'

```js
const { chromium } = require('playwright');
(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch({
        headless: false,
        executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome',
    });
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://whatsmyuseragent.org/');
    await page.screenshot({ path: `example-${browserType}.png` });
})();
```

Comment: While this code is correct, Playwright depends on new changes to Chromium upstream, and for that reason I would recommend using Chrome Canary instead of Chrome stable. You can get Canary from here: https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/

Let me know if that works!

Comment: It works ! The issue is it should be always the latest version of chrome to be installed in the local machine / the version that matches to Playwright chromium

Comment: +1 for the question. I had the same question on how to test  with an specific version of chrome ,i.e. 79/80.

Comment: Any luck with other browsers?

Answer (score 9):

You need to pick one of those flavors. But once you pick the browser type Chromium, you will still be able to pass an `executablePath` to the [`launch`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsertype#browser-type-launch) function.

Answer (score 9):

In 1.19 you can use chrome.

```
browser = playwright.chromium.launch(channel="chrome")
```

or you can simply put it in your playwright configuration file like:

```
////
    use: {
        headless: true,
        viewport: { width: 1600, height: 1000},
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        trace: 'on',
        screenshot: 'on',
        channel: "chrome",
        video: 'on'
    },
    ////
```

More on https://playwright.dev/python/docs/browsers

Answer (score 3):

You can specify browser path in config option

```
////
use: {
    headless: true,
    viewport: { width: 1600, height: 1000},
    launchOptions: {
        executablePath: '/path/to/the/browser',
    },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but in a Java/Maven project. The project runs behind strict corporate rules and I cannot download the binaries. So this won't solve your problem, but searching it only leads to this answer. Here is the solution that works for me in a JAVA/Maven Project:

I assume project dependencies are already set.

```
BrowserType chromium = playwright.chromium();
        System.out.println(chromium.executablePath());
        Browser browser = chromium.launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions()
                .setExecutablePath(Path.of("/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"));
```

The path here is for mac, but works fine on windows-paths.

After specifically pointing to the browser binary, you still have to disable downloads from playwright using the environment variable.
Like this
`PLAYWRIGHT_SKIP_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD=1 mvn test`

official docu:
https://playwright.dev/java/docs/browsers#skip-browser-downloads

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to set the [`channel`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsertype#browser-type-launch-persistent-context-option-channel) attribute to `chrome` via `playwright.config` file.

#### Cross project setting

```
export default defineConfig({
  use: {
    channel: "chrome", // Make all projects run on the computer's chrome browser
    headless: false,
  },
  projects: [
    {
      name: "Google Chrome",
    },
    {
      name: "Mobile Chrome",
      use: { ...devices["Pixel 5"] },
    },
  ],
});
```

All projects will use `channel: "chrome"` unless it's being overwritten by the project `use` settings like in the next example.

#### Specific Project setting

```
projects: [
  {
    name: "Google Chrome",
    use: { channel: "chrome" }, // This project will run on the computer's chrome browser
  },
  {
    name: 'Microsoft Edge',
    use: { channel: 'msedge' }, // This project will run on the computer's edge browser
  }
]
```