# Playwright/Context: Is there a way to create a browser context in a normal state and not in incognito?

Tags: browser, chromium, playwright, incognito-mode

Playwright seems to default in incognito mode and I would like to disable this so that I can have cookies remain consistent when navigating different web pages.

I've scavenged the entire Playwright documentation and they state that a new browser context defaults to incognito but did not provide a way to disable this option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use installed version of chrome in Playwright?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281859/how-to-use-installed-version-of-chrome-in-playwright)

Comment: Not quite because I don't mind using Chromium.  I want to use a non-incognito page context with Chromium. @ChristianBaumann

Answer (score 1):

You can use [launchPersistentContext](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsertype#browser-type-launch-persistent-context) to create new context in normal mode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example test that opens a non-incognito chromium window.

```js
import { test, expect, BrowserContext, Page, chromium } from '@playwright/test';

test('test', async () => {
  const browser: BrowserContext = await chromium.launchPersistentContext('', { headless: false, channel: 'chrome' });

  // remove extra tab in browser window hack
  const pages: Page[] = browser.pages();
  const page: Page = pages[0];

  await page.goto('https://www.example.com');
  await expect(page.locator('div').filter({ hasText: 'example' })).toBeVisible();
});
```

I referenced this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5uIFaBx738
which explains some of the details a little deeper than the Playwright documentation referenced by [RoseQuartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13953080/rosequartz).